# Regular Expression to detect a file extension

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression that will detect a filename from a string - see if it ends with .pdf, or .PDF - case insensitive. Should even match .Pdf or any variant of pdf in case the user has messy filenames.

This will be used in PHP 5. I know I can make a bunch of rows to test against each case, but I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Please be more specific. Is your string just one filename all by itself, or is it a longer string with one or more filenames along with some other text?

Answer (score 9):

There is nothing wrong with a regex, but there is also a [ready-made function](http://php.net/pathinfo) for dissecting a path and extracting the extension from it:

```
echo pathinfo("/path/to/myfile.txt", PATHINFO_EXTENSION); //.txt
```

Comment: Except this isn't actually pointing towards a file - the "title" field of the PDF attachments are determined by the filename that is put up, and then the users can override it (so a messy PDF title like REPORT_2008_PICNET.pdf can be turned into PICNET Financial Report (2008) but sometimes they may not override it, in which case I need to figure out whether to add the .pdf to the download headers or not. Thanks though.

Comment: @jeffkee I'm not sure I'm following you: Do you need to make sure that the file ends in .pdf? Then fetching the extension using `pathinfo()` will work. If you compare the lowercase version against "pdf", you will know whether you need to add the extension or not. Whether what you use is a full path, or a pure file name, should be meaningless to `pathinfo()`.

Comment: But doesn't the pathinfo() function only work on an actual file? These PDF "title" fields are fictitious, in a way. All PDFs are saved on the server in attachment[id].pdf format, and each has a corresponding title in the MySQL database.. hence the field string needs to be checked for the extension, not the actual file. All the files are automatically re-named to be .pdf anyway.

Comment: @jeffkee `print_r(pathinfo("somefile (2).test.txt.pdf"));` works as expected for me. `realpath()` depends on the specified path actually existing; `pathinfo()` does not.

Answer (score 0):

how about this one. I dont know what language you are using but here is a regex for matching anything ending in .pdf

```
.+([.][Pp][Dd][Ff]){1}
```

my bad. Im half asleep. PHP it is.
dont know php but that regex should work

Answer (score 0):

another possibility is to tolower the extension

```
strtolower(pathinfo("/path/file.pDf", PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) == ".pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, extracting the extension would work, otherwise you can do something like this.

`preg_match('/.*\.pdf/i', "match_me.pDf", $matches);`

Comment: Close, but `/.*\.pdf/i` needs an end-of-string anchor. Otherwise it matches: `file.pdflipingout.txt`

Answer (score 0):

If your string consists of a single filename here is a simple regex solution:

```
if (preg_match('/\.pdf$/i', $filename)) {
   // Its a PDF file
}
```