# look for a specific filetype in a directory in php and send it to a different directory after conversion

Tags: php, ffmpeg, mp3, mp4, scandir

I have a directory in which there is a **mp4 file** (including other files as well) which I want to convert into **mp3** and then send it to different directory. I have used the following **command line command** to covert into mp3 and its working perfectly fine.

```
ffmpeg -i 36031P.mp4 -map 0:2 -ac 1 floor_english.mp3
```

**mp4 file** is inside **in_folder**. Using ffmpeg, I want to **convert mp4 file into mp3** and send it to **out_folder**.

```
<?php
$dir    = 'in_folder';
$files1 = scandir($dir);
print_r($files1);    /* It lists all the files in a directory including mp4 file*/
?>
```

**print_r($files1)** lists all the file in a directory including mp4file.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what php code I need to write so that it looks for only **mp4 file inside the directory** and send it to **different directory (let say out_folder)** after converting into mp3.

The **pictorial representation** of what I want:

[image]

Comment: May I know the reason why its downvoted

Comment: Use `opendir` and `readdir` in a loop. In the loop, check for the file type and only copy those files.

Comment: Why not convert mp3 directly in the final folder or a subdirectory ;) or use [pathinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.pathinfo.php) to check files extension with a loop on [scandir](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.scandir.php)

Comment: How 'bout that bounty flash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In think it is what you want :

```php
<?php
$dir    = 'in_folder';
$files1 = scandir($dir);
print_r($files1);    /* It lists all the files in a directory including mp4 file*/

$destination = 'your new destination';

foreach($files1 as $f)
{
  $parts = pathinfo($f);
  if ($parts['extension'] = 'mp3';
  {
    // copy($f, $destination. DS . $parts['filename']. '.' . $parts['extension']);
    rename($f, $destination. DS . $parts['filename']. '.mp3');
  }
}
?>
```

Documentation [pathinfo](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.pathinfo.php)

Edit with convertion :

I think you can directly export your mp3 like this

```php
foreach($files1 as $f)
{
  $parts = pathinfo($f);
  if ($parts['extension'] = 'mp4';
  {
    // $result : the last line of the command output on success, and FALSE on failure. Optional.
    system('ffmpeg -i '.$f.' -map 0:2 -ac 1 '.$destination.DS. $parts['filename'].'.mp3', $result);
  }

  // See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php
  if ($result === false) {
    // Do something if failed
    // log for example
  } else {
    // command completed with code : $result
    // 0 by convention for exit with success EXIT_SUCCESS
    // 1 by convention for exit with error EXIT_ERROR
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199216/how-to-tell-if-ffmpeg-errored-or-not
  }
}
```

Documentation [system](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.system.php)

or do a first loop too convert mp4, and a second loop to copy mp3

Edit all in one :

```php
foreach($files1 as $f)
{
  $parts = pathinfo($f);

  switch(strtolower($parts['extension']))
  {
    case 'mp4' :
      // $result : the last line of the command output on success, and FALSE on failure. Optional.
      system('ffmpeg -i '.$f.' -map 0:2 -ac 1 '.$destination.DS. $parts['filename'].'.mp3', $result);

      // See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php
      if ($result === false) {
        // Do something if failed
        // log for example
      } else {
        // command completed with code : $result
        // 0 by convention for exit with success EXIT_SUCCESS
        // 1 by convention for exit with error EXIT_ERROR
        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199216/how-to-tell-if-ffmpeg-errored-or-not
      }
      break;

    case 'mp3' :
      // copy($f, $destination. DS . $parts['filename']. '.' . $parts['extension']);
      rename($f, $destination.DS.$parts['filename'].'.mp3');
      break;  
  }
}
```

**Edit 1** :
correction `strtolower($parts['extension'])` to check the extension of the file none case-sensitive.

or like this :

```php
strtolower(pathinfo("/path/file.mP4", PATHINFO_EXTENSION)) == ".mp4"
```

There is no need to use `preg_match` and `regexp` because `pathinfo` is a pre-made function to do the job and it works fine unless you use double named extension like `.tar.gz` for example.

[regular-expression-to-detect-a-file-extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656475/regular-expression-to-detect-a-file-extension)

**Edit 2** : Use `rename` instead of `copy` to move mp3.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It looks really great. I also want to include the conversion process as well in the code. I am wondering where I should I integrate ffmpeg process. It should work in way that it scans the directory to look for an mp4 file and then send it to different directory after converting it into mp3.

Comment: php code should scan a directory **(mp4 file inside Folder A)** to look for an mp4 file and then send it different directory **(mp3 file inside Folder B)** after converting it into mp3.

Comment: All the logic looks ok.  I copied your code in my codebase. Is there anything I am missing ? As it doesn't seem to convert mp4 into mp3 and sending it into different folder.

Comment: Probably we are close. Something is missing. I will post another question to come up with the answer.

Comment: I have a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56430459/how-to-convert-mp4-files-into-mp3-on-button-click-using-ffmpeg-php) related to ffmpeg. I am wondering if you can have a look.

Comment: I have a quick question regarding your code. I am wondering why did you add `$result` here `system('ffmpeg -i '.$f.' -map 0:2 -ac 1 '.$destination.DS. $parts['filename'].'.mp3', $result);` ?

Comment: You can look the documention here [system](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php). It is optional. The `system` function can return a value based on the command or `false` on failure. Use it or not, I don't know what value is returned from the command.

Comment: The return value is an integer and can be `0`. So if you check it `0` is not `false` ;)

Comment: Let say once the conversion is complete, I want **Conversion Completed** to be printed on the webpage.

Comment: I did something like this but it didn't work.        

                        `if($result) {
        echo "Conversion Completed";
        }`

Comment: You should do check like this:  `if($result !== false) { echo "Conversion Completed : " . $result; }` and echo code is a plus.

Comment: I added if(1) { echo “Hello World”; } and its not going inside that as well so I have a feeling there is something wrong with the code.

Comment: You should enable and provide PHP error to check what's going wrong `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194785/discussion-between-flash-and-shim-sao).

Comment: I don't know why I can't connect to the chatroom

Comment: I have enabled errors. I am wondering if I can send you the files so that you can have a look.

Comment: You can but I don't have ffmeg installed and I can't be sure to reproduce the error. Open a new question with code and the error you have. We will see. `echo` something line by line if there is no error. you will see if something fail without error, sometime it happen and you have a blank page. Be sure to have ffmpeg in your environment variables if you are on Windows. you can use exit to break the code for quick testing.

Comment: You will get more idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56533375/change-button-text-in-js-ajax-upon-process-completion-in-php/56536149#56536149) what I am trying to do. On click of a button, **JS/jQuery** code is called and then **convert.php** script. Anything which 
I am printing in **convert.php** script shows up at console as I am using `console.log(res)` in the success function in JS/jQuery code.

Answer (score 2):

I feel this could all be a bit more robust and shorter.

```php
<?php

// the folder to get MP4's from, recursively
$src_dir = 'folder/a';
// the destination to put MP3's in.
$dst_dir = 'folder/b';

// An iterator ('reader') that takes all files in src
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($src_dir)
);

// A filter, that only leaves entries ending with .mp4, case-insensitive.
$videos = new RegexIterator($files, '/^.+\.mp4$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::MATCH));

// Then, for each element in videos, convert to MP3
foreach ($videos as $video) {
    $src = $video->getPathname();
    // The destination is the basename without 'mp4', with 'mp3' appended.
    $dst = $dst_dir.'/'.$video->getBaseName($video->getExtension()).'mp3';

    system("ffmpeg -i $src -map 0:2 -ac 1 $dst");
}
```

You should take care that you don't allow 'user specified' names for files, but use your own (random) filenames. Avoid executing unvalidated user input at all cost!

Comment: I tried with your code. Its running till `// A filter, that only leaves entries ending with .mp4, case-insensitive.` The code is not going in after that line. Let me know what changes I need to make.

Answer (score 2):

This will do it. I tested the solution and it works.  I had to make one parameter change for the ffmpeg command. On my machine, it was throwing an error for the mapping. I added a question mark after the mapping to ignore the error.

The code assumes the following folder structure:
[image]

```
<?php

  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  $in_folder = sprintf("%s/mp4", __DIR__);
  $out_folder = sprintf("%s/mp3", __DIR__);

  if(!file_exists($in_folder)){
    mkdir($in_folder);
  }

  if(!file_exists($out_folder)){
    mkdir($out_folder);
  }

  $items = scandir($in_folder);
  foreach($items as $item){
    if(preg_match('/^.*\.mp4$/', $item)){
      $file_name = str_replace(".mp4", "", $item);
      $in_file = sprintf("%s/%s.mp4", $in_folder, $file_name);
      $out_file = sprintf("%s/%s.mp4", $out_folder, $file_name);
      if(file_exists($out_file)){
        unlink($out_file);
      }
      $cmd = sprintf("ffmpeg -i %s -map 0:2? -ac 1 %s", $in_file, $out_file);
      print "$cmd\n";
      exec($cmd);
    }
  }

?>
```